# jQuery select n-th child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a

```
ul
  > li
  > li
  > li
  > li
</>
```

I want to do something when hovering li's but it has to be slightly different regarding the number of the current selected li. I can do it with data-toggle but I don't want to use it that way.

**So my question is how can I calculate which serial li I have selected within a ul?**

eg: first;second;third

Comment: Can you add your js code please?

Comment: Do you mean something like the nth-child selector? http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: I want to do something different for every li but it has something to do with the li's before the selected one.

Biduleohm - a little pseudo code:

$('li.1')-> var x *= 1;
$('li.2')-> var x *= 2;
$('li.3')-> var x *= 3;
$('li.4')-> var x *= 4;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$('li').mouseover(function () {
    var _in = $(this).index();
    switch(_in) {
        case 0:
            alert('You hovered the first <li>!');
        break;
        case 1:
            alert('You hovered the second <li>!');
        break;
        case 2:
            alert('You hovered the third <li>!');
        break;
    }
});
```

- Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xrz93/

Comment: Bull's eye! That does the job perfectly, thank you!

Comment: The mouseout should also be taken in consideration. For example if you add somehting, you should be able to remove it as well

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$('li').mouseover(function(){
    var x = $(this).index();
})
```

From the docs:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Note that `.index()` is zero-based.